# Convert HttpError to JSON

Tags: django

In my Django app in several places I do:

```
raise HttpError(
    message="Bla bla bla",
    status=400,
)
```

Is there some way to intercept all HttpErrors being raised and wrap them in a nice JSON body? Something like:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message":" "Bla bla bla"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) is the place where you should do the job.

Create a middleware class, define [process_exception()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process_exception) method; in case of `HttpError` return a json response, otherwise return `None` (do not re-raise the exception):

> Django calls `process_exception()` when a view raises an exception.
>   `process_exception()` should return either `None` or an `HttpResponse`
>   object. If it returns an `HttpResponse` object, the template response
>   and response middleware will be applied, and the resulting response
>   returned to the browser. Otherwise, default exception handling kicks
>   in.

Here's an example:

```
class CustomMiddleware():
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if not isinstance(exception, HttpError):
            return None

        response = json.dumps({'status': exception.status, 
                               'message': exception.message})
        return HttpResponse(response, 
                            content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

Also, don't forget to add your middleware to [MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) setting.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create or find middleware that will catch the exception and check the URI or view to see if it should convert the exception or reraise it.